# Reversing a linked list recursively in a class method

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have the following instance variables inside my `SinglyLinkedList` class.

```
/* head is a reference to the front of the list (first element)
 * by default, head is initialized to null */
private Node head;

/* tail is a reference to the back of the list (last element)
 * by default, tail is initialized to null */
private Node tail; 

/* length is an integer that represents the size of our list,
 * by default it is assigned a value of 0 */
protected int length;
```

What I would like to do is write a method called `recursiveReverse()` that reverses a `SinglyLinkedList` object recursively. Such as `list.recursiveReverse()`

I have some ideas which don't seem to be working without passing in a Node object

```
public SinglyLinkedList recursiveReverse() {
    static Node temp = head;
    if(temp == null) return null;
    if(length == 1) return this;

    Node temp_2 = temp.next;
    temp.next = null;
    // here is where i am stuck with the recursive call
    // is passing a Node as an argument the only way ?
    // if so, then how do I pass it in a class method ?
    // make the method static ?
 }
```

Comment: You've declared a variable inside a method as static - what are you trying to do there? That wouldn't even compile, and there's no need to have it static.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    if(head==null || head.next == null)
        return head;

    //get second node    
    ListNode second = head.next;
    //set first's next to be null
    head.next = null;

    ListNode rest = reverseList(second);
    second.next = head;

    return rest;
}
```

Reference: [Reverse a Singly Linked List.](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-reverse-linked-list-java/)